# Tag mouseover "unsubscribe" text too big

Tags: bug, design

[image: screen shot]

Found this when subscribing to jQuery tag. "unsubscribe | rss" is not shown correctly.

Comment: Is this on Stack Overflow only? If so, why didn't you post it on the Meta there? Also, please include your browser (version) and OS.

Comment: What browser / OS are you using? I cannot reproduce this (see http://i.stack.imgur.com/b4uqU.png)

Comment: Firefox 31.0, bug is still there today (08.09.2014)